# Why immutable null is discouraged?

Tags: java, java-8, guava, nullable, immutables-library

I'm currently using Immutable library for generating JSON object from my web application.

Looking at [this](https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#nullable-attributes) chapter, the first line says:

> The use of nullable attributes is discouraged.

So my question is:

1) why? what's wrong with a null object?

2) what if I'm using a wrapper of thirdy object and I don't know if item is null or not, so using the classing builder code will fail:

```
MyImmutableWrapperObject
    .builder().
    .mobile(input.getMobile()) // don't know if null or not
    .build();
```

Is there any optimal solution?

EDIT:

```
@JsonProperty("mobile")
public abstract Optional<String> mobile();  

...

// composing builder
if (input.getMobile() != null)
        builder.mobile(input.getMobile());
```

The produced json is:

```
"mobile": {
    "present": false
},
```

How can I completely remove the empty fields?

I read [this](https://immutables.github.io/json.html#omitting-empty-fields), however it uses gson.toJson which return a String object which is not my desiderable way.

POSTEDIT:

I just found that **Optional** doesn't show real value even if present, but it just display the true/false value, so I don't need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's exactly the point IMO, you don't know if an object is null or not; so when later using it you might obviously get a `NullPointerException`. By using a library that prohibits that, you will not care if something is null or not null (because it will not be null), thus less code and less `if`-statements that pollute the code with potential null checks.

Also having a null reference might mean different things in different contexts. For example I've seen code that needs three states for a `Boolean` : `true`, `false` and no yet set(as `null`). I find that wrong, but still occasionally see it.

That's the reason why `Optional` was introduced in Guava and now is in the JDK. It forces the user to actively do something with an `Optional`. For example:

```
  Optional<Integer> i...

  if(i.isPresent()).... // you are forced to do this check
```

Well obviously you could do:

```
 i.get()
```

but that method is documented that it might break.

the same is simply not true for an reference:

```
 Integer i  = null;
 if(i == null) // this is not an operation that is mandatory
```

The bet article I've seen/read to date on this subject is [Guava explanation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)

Comment: So a possibile way could be also:
Builder builder = ImmutableAccount
    .builder()
if (input.getMobile() != null) builder.mobile(input.getMobile()); return builder.build()

Comment: @FabrizioStellato it could be - yes. It could be right in your case to store an `Optional.empty()` in this case. Or even for the builder to do something with this null instead - it depends.

Comment: See my EDITED question

Comment: @FabrizioStellato looks like you need to annotate your field with `@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_ABSENT)`